# API Connecting to GDS and IDS (hotels distribution channels)

Tags: api, rest, channel

I have one question about gds and ids for hotel my own reservation system.
Developed my own reservation system for my hotel and i need solution to connect my API with GDS and IDS.
I need to manage my distibution channel with other channels easily and automatically based my own hotel inventory with other channels 
like booking , expedia , venere and GDS like Amadeus Gallilelo Sabre and Worldspan.
Do you have any idea how can do this connection ? (I need a service to do this and i dont know how can find it)

Comment: What kind of connection/service are you looking for? Do you want online agencies and GDS to connect to your system to distribute your hotel? Or do you want to connect to the websites and GDS to get content from them (e.g. book a flight to your hotel)?

Comment: The first example i have my own hotel and i need to sychronize my prices with other GDS and IDS as a channel manager!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an open standard to expose your hotel availability to distributors, you should probably use Open Travel Alliance (OTA) standards: http://www.opentravel.org/

However these standards are quite recent and not widely implemented. For example TripAdvisor has its own API: http://developer.tripadvisor.com/index.html
Same thing for GDS systems.

Moreover, you will anyway have to contact each agency / GDS independently to know their conditions and pricing.